# Set up error while installing SP 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, installation, service-pack

When I try to install SP 2013 SP1 on a new machine [ Win Server 2012 R2 OS server], am getting the below error message.
What am I missing here?

> setup cant find or validate an installation file.Please try reinstalling Office from your installation source.

[image: seuperror-from-media]

Comment: Where did you locate the installation files? it's recommended to reduce the path length to the installation files!

Comment: The installation media - DVD - has been mounted on a Drive in the server.From the mounted drive, we just ran the pre-requisite installer exe / `flash` file.

Answer (score 1):

You DVD file is not readable from the system, may be corrupted. I would do following steps to install SharePoint.

- If it is ISO package, re download it
- Extract it to the drive i.e C:\sp2013
- Now run the Splah.htm file or run the pre-req installer exe file.